# How to subscribe to eddystone/ibeacon?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I need to be able to subscribe to the identifier and for this subscription to work even with the application closed. I know such a feature is in native applications. Is there something similar for ionics?

Sample algorithm:

1) Make a subscription

2) The application is unloaded from the device memory

3) When the device detects the desired identifier does an action or calls my application

Did someone do something similar? How can this be done on ionics?

Comment: Do you mean you want your app to be like google service app, which deliver firebase notifications to specific apps or i got you wrong?(you don't want notifications but you want similar proccess?).

Comment: If I understand correctly, native applications do subscription through the services of the operating system. I need to be able to subscribe similarly using ionic.

Comment: Subscribe to what give me an example to what kind of subscription you want?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwnmx-5mBLM

Comment: Ok now i got you, every thing can be made with ionic, but not everything is provided by ionic, in such cases, you could create your own server on node js which keeps app updated by realtime, in you app you add geolocation in background mode to track user and update location on system, and the node js role comes in role to analyze the places nearby or people or offers or etc... and now we go to the latest part that was in video that it works on bluetooth, and ionic offers bluetooth plugins, if i still didn't let you understand well or not gotting the exact point tell me.